# How can I jump to next html validation warning in Visual Web Developer Express 2010?

Tags: visual-web-developer

When editing HTML in Visual Web Developer Express 2010 syntax errors in the markup are highlighted (with green squiggly lines) as warnings (see example below).

[image: example warning]

Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to next warning within current document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> or change the `View.NextError` keyboard shortcut in options.